# Changing td's html in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, innerhtml

I want to change text in table td from 1,1,1 to 1,2,3 with jQuery
But it not seem to work. what is wrong in my code?

This is my JavaScript function.

```
    function reorder(targetId){
        var i = 1;
        jQuery.find(targetId).each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr("innerHTML", i);
            i ++;
        });
    }
```

My html code.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onClick="reorder('#index');" value="test"/>
    <table>
        <tr><td id="index">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="index">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="index">1</td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a bit of mixed up stuff there. Try this...

```
function reorder(selector){
     jQuery(selector)
      .find('tr td:first-child')
      // Remove the + 1 if you want it to start at 0.          
      .html(function(i) { return i + 1; });
}
```

Here are some of the changes...

- Changed your argument variable to be clearer.
- You can use jQuery('selector'), not `jQuery.find()`.
- You can use the `html()` method.

It's worth mentioning too that if you're not using another jQuery library (or don't intend to), you can use `$` which is shorter than `jQuery`.

I've also modified your HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="reorder('#my-table');" value="test"/>
    <table id="my-table">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

You may have forgot that using multiple `id` attributes with the same value is not valid markup. You could use a class there, or better still omit it entirely. You may not care about valid markup, but browsers' CSS and JavaScript *could* do some funky stuff (now or in the future) when they expect an `id` attribute to unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change i values incrementation expression  .

```
function reorder(targetId){
        var i = 1;
        jQuery.find(targetId).each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr("innerHTML", i);
            i++; // Before that it was i ++ 
        });
    }
```